# Link content type to view (for search)

Tags: drupal-7, view, content-type, pathauto

I have a content type 'product display'.

The normal path is: node/[nid]

with the module 'pathauto' I can do the following for each 'product display':
node/[id] ==> product/detail/[node:nid]

This works fine, but it doesn't trigger the view.

1) Page settings (for the view)
Path: product/detail/%

2) URL path settings (for the content type 'product display'):
Generate automatic URL alias

When I use the standard search box, the product is found and the link is ok but I shows the normal standard page where you can edit the node.

Need some advice, help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is enough information to answer this accurately, but I'll give it a shot.

You said you created a view and you made the path, product/detail/%, so I'm assuming you're using Views. Under Advanced, add a contextual filter for Nid. Under *When the filter value is NOT in the URL*, select **Provide default value -> Content ID from URL**.

Hopefully that solves your issue.